# Removing Kitchen Ceiling Fixture

Tags: electrical

We are replacing a kitchen ceiling light with a fan.  We have removed the globe, but we can't remove the fixture pan.  There are no screws.  The fixture appears to be attached to the ceiling.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes. Suggestion one: post a photo.

Comment: Ceiling fans require special boxes for support, if you cannot access the attic to remove the old box and possible straps if between trusses you will probably need to remove some Sheetrock and install a cross brace to hang the new box on.